# What can I do about a SQL Server ghost FK constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I'm having some trouble with a SQL Server 2005 database that seems like it's keeping a ghost constraint around. I've got a script that drops the constraint in question, does some work, and then re-adds the same constraint. Normally, it works fine. Now, however, it can't re-add the constraint because the database says that it already exists, even though the drop worked fine!

Here are the queries I'm working with:

```
alter table individual drop constraint INDIVIDUAL_EMP_FK

ALTER TABLE INDIVIDUAL
   ADD CONSTRAINT INDIVIDUAL_EMP_FK
          FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID)
                         REFERENCES EMPLOYEE
```

After the constraint is dropped, I've made sure that the object really is gone by using the following queries:

```
select object_id('INDIVIDUAL_EMP_FK')
select * from sys.foreign_keys where name like 'individual%'
```

Both return no results (or null), but when I try to add the query again, I get:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "INDIVIDUAL_EMP_FK".
```

Trying to drop it gets me a message that it doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the data is wrong on creation of the FK

That is, you have "EMPLOYEE_ID" values in the INDIVIDUAL child table that don not exist in the parent EMPLOYEE table.

You could use `ALTER TABLE ...WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT...` but then the FK is no use

Comment: Exactly. The message is about the constraint INDIVIDUAL_EMP_FK that was *just added* and is being now verified. The verification fails, the implicit transaction rolls back and the newly added constraint is gone.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what it was. It was the error message referring to the FK i was trying to add that threw me off. Thanks for the help!